# Removing at most one occurrence of an item from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of integers and I want to delete only one item from that list, not duplicate ones. The list is dynamic so I don't know the item index position.

```
public List<int> checkpass (int a, int b, int c, int d, ... int z, int remove1, remove2)
{
    List<int> mylist = new List<int>(){a,b,c,d,....,z};
    // For Example 
    //List<int> mylist = new List<int>(){1,2,0,4,0,7,0,1};
    mylist.Remove(remove1); // 0
    mylist.Remove(remove2); // 4
}
```

The output from this should be:

```
1,2,0,7,0,1
```

Comment: if you want to remove a specific item you ll have to remove by position. You cannot delegate that task to the framework. You´ll have to use RemoveAt(int index)

Comment: Do you know the value of the item that you want removed?

Comment: Does `List.Remove` not already have the functionality you require? According to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx), it will only remove the first occurrence of an element.

Comment: @Tagc, In my case its removing all 0 from list , don't know why

Comment: Remove() does it , everybody has already told. If u still hav doubt check the size of the list before and after. it will be n-1 after.

Comment: your code is placed inside a loop? that would be the only possible way that all zeros are removed from the list.

Comment: `mylist.remove(remove1); ` should be `mylist.Remove(remove1);` as already suggested by @swatsonpicken

Comment: Is it possible that you have an extension method named `remove` that removes all items?  That's really the only thing that would make sense here.

Comment: @juharr +1 and I'm against editing the question to fix the capitalisation on `remove` as your suggestion seems the most likely, and people viewing this question post-edit would have no chance of spotting that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
myList.RemoveAt(myList.indexOf(0));
```

And more generalized version would be:

```
void RemoveFirst<T>(List<T> list, T item)
{
    var indexOfItem = list.IndexOf(item);

    if(indexOfItem != -1)
        list.RemoveAt(indexOfItem);
}
```

Note: What `.Remove()` does shold be crystal clear to everyone. But when one wants to see the logic behind it, I think my answer still has some value.

Comment: Hold on dude, checking

Comment: @Tolga Evcimen it removes all the 0 from list, but Stackfull wants to remove second item in list only

Comment: Since I call `RemoveAt` at the end it can remove at most 1 item.

Comment: not work dude, I don't know about the index of the item because its dynamic ,

Comment: `.IndexOf` will give you the index of the item.

Comment: Well, I personnaly tried it out, and it's working. If you update your question with the codes I've proposed, we can figure it out.

Comment: `List.Remove()` already only removes the first item, so this is redundant...

Comment: I know, but always fun to rewrite small logics like this one :) When you know these shortcuts you don't get to play with these kind of stuff, so here we are.

Comment: Great dude, it's worked,  Thank you very much for your answer. It's really hard understanding, what wrong with other guys,  Why they marking my question negative!!

Comment: @Stackfull You're getting down voted because you haven't given us code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Juharr,  Thank you for your message but people should understand everyone has own privacy and can't share whole code!

Comment: @Stackfull Then you should understand that if you don't provide a [MCVE] you will get downvoted and people will not be able to understand your problem

Comment: @Stackfull You don't have to dump your exact code here, just attempt to create a small bit of code that reproduces the problem.  9 times out of 10 doing that will actually show you the issue and you won't even need to post a question.

Comment: @Stackfull There is absolutely no way this custom method to work differently from the standard `List<T>.Remove`  method. Your question is flawed from the beginning and even now it's not clear what the problem was and why do you think this answer is solving it (we all doubt that).

Answer (score 4):

The code in the question snippet already does what you want:

```
mylist.Remove(0);
```

Put your cursor in `Remove` and hit F12. That takes you to the docs for `List<>.Remove()` :

> Summary: Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the System.Collections.Generic.List<>.

Answer (score 2):

Your code literally already does that, as `List<T>.Remove` only removes the first occurrence of an element from a list:

```
List<int> mylist = new List<int>(){1,2,0,4,0,7,0,1};
mylist.Remove(0);

Console.WriteLine(mylist);
```

**Output** (using LINQPad)

```
1 2 4 0 7 0 1
```

Comment: no,its not work

Comment: @Stackfull In what way does your output differ from mine?

Comment: Well, `Console.WriteLine(mylist);` won't show that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I ran the code in LINQPad and copied the output. I've clarified that now in my post.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out,

```
myList.Remove(0);
```

works. Be aware that C# is case sensitive so

```
myList.remove(0);
```

will not work!

Comment: `.remove()` wouldn't even compile, the question is about why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Agreed. The OP is saying .remove is not working, but hasn't detailed _how_ it is not working so non-compilation _could_ be the issue for them.

Comment: Possibly there's an extension method for List defined called `remove()`. Unlikely, yes, but possible...

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<int> mylist = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 7, 0, 1 };

            mylist.Remove(0);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", mylist));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```